# How to remove whitespace from the string of list

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, whitespace

I would like to remove whitespace of the string of the list as following

```
original = ['16', '0000D1AE18', '1', '1', '1', 'S O S .jpg', '0']
```

after remove the whitespace

```
['16', '0000D1AE18', '1', '1', '1', 'SOS.jpg', '0']
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`str.translate()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate) on each element in a list comprehension:

```
[v.translate(None, ' ') for v in original]
```

Here `None` means *don't replace characters with other characters*, and `' '` means *remove spaces altogether*. This produces a *new* list to replace the original.

The above only removes just the *spaces*. To remove all whitespace (newlines, tabs, feeds, etc.) simply expand what characters should be removed

```
[v.translate(None, ' \t\r\n\f\x0a') for v in original]
```

`str.translate()` is the fastest option for removing characters from text.

Demo:

```
>>> original = ['16', '0000D1AE18', '1', '1', '1', 'S O S .jpg', '0']
>>> [v.translate(None, ' \t\r\n\f\x0a') for v in original]
['16', '0000D1AE18', '1', '1', '1', 'SOS.jpg', '0']
```

Comment: this returns spaces, not all whitespace. Admittedly, the question isn't clear on whether the OP wants to remove just spaces or not.

Comment: @BryanOakley: I'm going by the sample; we can always split and rejoin otherwise.

Comment: @BryanOakley: thinking about this some more; `str.translate()` is the better option anyway.

Comment: I haven't heard about `translate()`. Looks nice! and of course better that the iteration I suggested

Answer (score 1):

If you want to remove any whitespace (i.e.**Space**, **Tab**, **CR** and **Newline**), use this:

```
import re

without_spaces = [re.sub(r'\s+', '', item) for item in original]
```

If you need to replace only regular spaces, use the already suggested solution

```
without_spaces = [item.replace(' ', '') for item in original]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
k=[]
for i in original :
    j = i.replace(' ','')
    k.append(j)
```

Comment: I would always use list comprehension if possible